# Facebook sdk io getting photo's from album

Tags: ios, xcode, facebook, sdk, photos

I got the facebook sdk op and running. I try to get all the photos of an album. Currently i'm using this:

```
NSString *S = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%s%@%s","https://graph.facebook.com/",albumID, "/photos"];
[facebook requestWithGraphPath:S andDelegate:self];
```

I also get a result and i try to parse that to an array of photo's or photo ID's. But I tried for hours and search the web every where but I cant find a solution. What am I doing wrong?

```
- (void)request:(FBRequest *)request didLoad:(id)result


        for (NSDictionary *anAlbum in [result objectForKey:@"data"]) {
            [arrayAllPhotos addObject:[anAlbum objectForKey:@"id"]];

            NSString *url = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"https://graph.facebook.com/%@/picture",[arrayAllPhotos objectAtIndex:counter]];

            UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:url]]];
        }
}
```

This is the JSON I get back from Facebook. Thanks in advance!

```
{
   "data": [
      {
         "id": "244119762368747",
         "from": {
            "name": "Eindhovens Studenten Corps Intro",
            "category": "Non-profit organization",
            "id": "235447296569327"
         },
         "picture": "http://photos-g.ak.fbcdn.net/hphotos-ak-snc7/392553_244119762368747_67274374_s.jpg",
         "source": "http://a7.sphotos.ak.fbcdn.net/hphotos-ak-snc7/s720x720/392553_244119762368747_67274374_n.jpg",
         "height": 480,
         "width": 720,
         "images": [
            {
               "height": 1365,
               "width": 2048,
               "source": "http://a7.sphotos.ak.fbcdn.net/hphotos-ak-snc7/s2048x2048/392553_244119762368747_67274374_n.jpg"
            },
            {
               "height": 640,
               "width": 960,
               "source": "http://a7.sphotos.ak.fbcdn.net/hphotos-ak-snc7/392553_244119762368747_67274374_n.jpg"
            },
            {
               "height": 480,
               "width": 720,
               "source": "http://a7.sphotos.ak.fbcdn.net/hphotos-ak-snc7/s720x720/392553_244119762368747_67274374_n.jpg"
            },
            {
               "height": 320,
               "width": 480,
               "source": "http://a7.sphotos.ak.fbcdn.net/hphotos-ak-snc7/s480x480/392553_244119762368747_67274374_n.jpg"
            },
            {
               "height": 213,
               "width": 320,
               "source": "http://a7.sphotos.ak.fbcdn.net/hphotos-ak-snc7/s320x320/392553_244119762368747_67274374_n.jpg"
            },
            {
               "height": 120,
               "width": 180,
               "source": "http://photos-g.ak.fbcdn.net/hphotos-ak-snc7/392553_244119762368747_67274374_a.jpg"
            },
            {
               "height": 86,
               "width": 130,
               "source": "http://photos-g.ak.fbcdn.net/hphotos-ak-snc7/392553_244119762368747_67274374_s.jpg"
            },
            {
               "height": 86,
               "width": 130,
               "source": "http://photos-g.ak.fbcdn.net/hphotos-ak-snc7/s75x225/392553_244119762368747_67274374_s.jpg"
            }
         ]
```

Comment: This is perfect.     NSString *graphPath = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%@/photos",albumId];
    Facebook *fb = //your facebookSDK;
    [fb requestWithGraphPath:graphPath andDelegate:self];

Answer (score 1):

when you add objects to your `arrayAllPhotos` use `source` instead of `id`:

```
[arrayAllPhotos addObject:[NSUrl urlWithString:[anAlbum objectForKey:@"source"]]];
```

oh and then when you want to use these images do this:

```
UIImage *image = [[UIImage imageWithData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfUrl:[arrayAllPhotos objectAtIndex:indexOfObjectYouWant]]]];
```

hope it helps